# Get HTML in String Array?

Tags: android, arrays, superscript

How can we display HTML in String Array from strings.xml
please help me!
thanks you very much

jave code:

```
details.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.array.GE)));
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="GE">
<item>
   <![CDATA[<sup><small>១</small></sup> កាល​ដើម​ដំបូង​ឡើយ ព្រះ​បាន​បង្កើត​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី។]]>
    ២ ឯ​ផែនដី​បាន​ខូច ហើយ​នៅ​ទទេ មាន​សុទ្ធ​តែ​ងងឹត​នៅ​គ្រប​លើ​ជំរៅ​ទឹក ហើយ​ព្រះវិញ្ញាណ​នៃ​ព្រះ​ក៏​រេរា​នៅ​ពី​លើ​ទឹក ៣ នោះ​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ពន្លឺ​ឡើង ដូច្នេះ ពន្លឺ​ក៏​មាន​ឡើង។ ៤ ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ឃើញ​ពន្លឺ​នោះ​ក៏​យល់​ថា​ជា​ល្អ​ហើយ រួច​ទ្រង់​ញែក​ពន្លឺ​ពី​ងងឹត​ចេញ ៥ ទ្រង់​ហៅ​ពន្លឺ​ថា​ជា​ថ្ងៃ ហើយ​ហៅ​ងងឹត​ថា​ជា​យប់ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច​មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​១។
    ៦ បន្ទាប់​មក ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ប្រឡោះ​នៅ​កណ្តាល​ទឹក ដើម្បី​ញែក​ទឹក​ចេញ​ពី​គ្នា ៧ ទ្រង់​ក៏​ធ្វើ​ប្រឡោះ​នោះ ទាំង​ញែក​ទឹក​ដែល​នៅ​ក្រោម​ប្រឡោះ​ចេញ​ពី​ទឹក​ដែល​នៅ​លើ​ប្រឡោះ ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ៨ រួច​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ហៅ​ប្រឡោះ​នោះ​ថា​ជា​មេឃ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច​មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​២។
    កំណើត​ពិភព​លោក ៩ បន្ទាប់​មក ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​ទឹក​នៅ​ក្រោម​មេឃ​ប្រមូល​គ្នា​នៅ​កន្លែង​តែ​១ ហើយ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ទី​គោក​ដុះ​លេច​ឡើង នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ១០ ទ្រង់​ហៅ​ទី​គោក​នោះ​ថា​ជា​ដី ហើយ​ទី​ទឹក​ដែល​ប្រមូល​គ្នា​នោះ​ថា​ជា​សមុទ្រ នោះ​ទ្រង់​ក៏​ឃើញ​ថា​ល្អ ១១ រួច​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​ដី​ដុះ​តិណជាតិ​ឡើង គឺ​ជា​ពួក​ស្មៅ​ដែល​មាន​គ្រាប់ និង​រុក្ខ​ជាតិ​មាន​ផ្លែ​តាម​ពូជ ដែល​មាន​គ្រាប់​ក្នុង​ផ្លែ​នោះ​នៅ​ផែនដី នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ១២ ដី​ក៏​ដុះ​តិណជាតិ​ទាំងឡាយ​ឡើង គឺ​ជា​ពួក​ស្មៅ​ដែល​មាន​គ្រាប់​តាម​ពូជ និង​រុក្ខជាតិ​មាន​ផ្លែ​តាម​ពូជ​ដែរ ហើយ​មាន​គ្រាប់​នៅ​ក្នុង​ផ្លែ​នោះ​ឯង រួច​ទ្រង់​ឃើញ​ថា​ល្អ ១៣ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច​មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៣។
    ១៤ បន្ទាប់​មក ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​មាន​តួ​ពន្លឺ​នៅ​នា​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ ដើម្បី​នឹង​ញែក​ថ្ងៃ​ចេញ​ពី​យប់ សំរាប់​ទុក​ជា​ទី​សំគាល់​នៃ​រដូវ ថ្ងៃ និង​ឆ្នាំ ១៥ ហើយ​សំរាប់​ជា​ពន្លឺ​នៅ​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ ដើម្បី​បំភ្លឺ​មក​ផែនដី នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ១៦ ទ្រង់​ធ្វើ​ពន្លឺ​ធំ​ជា​២​តួ ១​ដែល​ធំ​ជាង នោះ​សំរាប់​បំភ្លឺ​ក្នុង​ពេល​ថ្ងៃ ហើយ​១​ដែល​តូច​ជាង​សំរាប់​បំភ្លឺ​ក្នុង​ពេល​យប់ ក៏​ធ្វើ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ផ្កាយ​ទាំង​ប៉ុន្មាន​ដែរ។ ១៧ ទ្រង់​ដាក់​តួ​ពន្លឺ​ទាំង​នោះ​នៅ​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ សំរាប់​នឹង​បំភ្លឺ​មក​លើ​ផែនដី ១៨ ឲ្យ​មាន​អំណាច​នៅ​ពេល​ថ្ងៃ និង​ពេល​យប់ ហើយ​ឲ្យ​ញែក​ពន្លឺ​ចេញ​ពី​ងងឹត រួច​ទ្រង់​ឃើញ​ថា​ជា​ល្អ ១៩ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៤។
    ២០ បន្ទាប់​មក ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​មាន​មច្ឆាជាតិ​រវើក​នៅ​ក្នុង​ទឹក​ជា​បរិបូរ និង​បក្សី​ជាតិ​ហើរ​លើ​ដី​នៅ​នា​អាកាស ២១ ទ្រង់​ក៏​បង្កើត​អស់​ទាំង​សត្វ​សំបើមៗ និង​ជីវិត​ទាំងឡាយ​ដែល​កំរើក ដែល​កើត​មាន​រវិនរវ័ណ្ឌ​នៅ​ក្នុង​ទឹក​តាម​ពូជ ហើយ​អស់​ទាំង​សត្វ​ស្លាប​តាម​ពូជ​ដែរ រួច​ទ្រង់​ឃើញ​ថា​ល្អ ២២ ទ្រង់​ក៏​ប្រទាន​ពរ​ដល់​សត្វ​ទាំងឡាយ​នោះ ហើយ​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​បង្កើត​កូន​ឲ្យ​ចំរើន​ជា​ច្រើន​ឡើង ឲ្យ​មាន​ពេញពាស​នៅ​ក្នុង​ទឹក​សមុទ្រ ហើយ​ឲ្យ​សត្វ​ស្លាប​ចំរើន​ឡើង​នៅ​ផែនដី​ដែរ ២៣ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៥។
    ២៤ បន្ទាប់​មក ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ចតុប្បាទ​ជាតិ​កើត​មក​នៅ​ដី​គោក​តាម​ពូជ គឺ​ជា​សត្វ​ស្រុក​សត្វ​លូន​វារ និង​សត្វ​ព្រៃ​នៅ​ផែនដី​តាម​ពូជ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ២៥ ទ្រង់​ក៏​ធ្វើ​សត្វ​ព្រៃ​នៅ​ផែនដី​តាម​ពូជ សត្វ​ស្រុក​តាម​ពូជ ហើយ​គ្រប់​ទាំង​សត្វ​ដែល​លូន​វារ​នៅ​ដី​គោក​តាម​ពូជ រួច​ទ្រង់​ឃើញ​ថា​ល្អ ២៦ ទ្រង់​ក៏​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​យើង​ធ្វើ​មនុស្សឲ្យ​ដូច​ជា​រូប​យើង ឲ្យ​មាន​ភាព​ដូច​យើង ហើយ​ឲ្យ​មាន​អំណាច​លើ​ត្រី​សមុទ្រ សត្វ​ហើរ​លើ​អាកាស និង​សត្វ​ជើង​៤​ដែល​នៅ​លើ​ផែនដី​ទាំង​មូល ព្រម​ទាំង​សត្វ​លូន​វារ​ដែល​វារ​នៅ​លើ​ផែនដី​ផង ២៧ ទ្រង់​ក៏​បង្កើត​មនុស្ស​ឲ្យ​ដូច​រូប​អង្គ​ទ្រង់ គឺ​បាន​បង្កើត​គេ​ឲ្យ​ចំ​នឹង​រូប​អង្គ​ទ្រង់​នោះ​ឯង ក៏​បង្កើត​គេ​ឡើង​ជា​ប្រុស​ជា​ស្រី ២៨ ទ្រង់​ប្រទាន​ពរ​ដល់​គេ ហើយ​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ចូរ​បង្កើត​កូន​ឲ្យ​ចំរើន​ជា​ច្រើន​ឡើង ឲ្យ​មាន​ពេញពាស​លើ​ផែនដី​ចុះ ត្រូវ​បង្ក្រាប​ផែនដី ហើយ​មាន​អំណាច​លើ​ត្រី​សមុទ្រ សត្វ​ហើរ​លើ​អាកាស និង​ជីវិត​ផង​ទាំងឡាយ​ដែល​កំរើក​នៅ​ផែនដី​ផង ២៩ ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា មើល អញ​ឲ្យ​គ្រប់​ទាំង​តិណជាតិ​មាន​គ្រាប់​ពូជ​ដែល​ដុះ​នៅ​លើ​ផែនដី និង​គ្រប់​ទាំង​រុក្ខជាតិ​ទាំងឡាយ​ដែល​កើត​ផ្លែ​មាន​គ្រាប់​ពូជ ទុក​ជា​អាហារ​ដល់​ឯង ៣០ ហើយ​អញ​ក៏​ឲ្យ​គ្រប់​ទាំង​តិណជាតិ​ខ្ចីៗ ទុក​ជា​អាហារ​ដល់​អស់​ទាំង​សត្វ​នៅ​លើ​ដី សត្វ​ហើរ​លើ​អាកាស និង​សត្វ​លូន​វារ​នៅ​ដី ដែល​មាន​ជីវិត​ទាំង​ប៉ុន្មាន​ដែរ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ដូច្នោះ ៣១ រួច​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ទត​គ្រប់​ទាំង​របស់​ដែល​ទ្រង់​បាន​ធ្វើ​នោះ ក៏​ឃើញ​ថា ទាំង​អស់​ជា​ការ​ល្អ​ប្រពៃ នោះ​ក៏​មាន​ល្ងាច មាន​ព្រឹក​ឡើង ជា​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៦។
</item>
<item>
    ១ ដូច្នេះ ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី​ក៏​បាន​រួច​ជា​ស្រេច ព្រម​ទាំង​របស់​សព្វ​សារពើ​ផង ២ លុះ​ដល់​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៧ ការ​ដែល​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ធ្វើ នោះ​បាន​ហើយ​ជា​ស្រេច ទ្រង់​ក៏​ឈប់​ផ្អាក​សំរាក​នៅ​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៧​នោះ ពី​គ្រប់​ទាំង​ការ​ដែល​ទ្រង់​ធ្វើ ៣ ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ក៏​ប្រទាន​ពរ​ដល់​ថ្ងៃ​ទី​៧​នោះ ព្រម​ទាំង​ញែក​ទុក​ជា​ថ្ងៃ​បរិសុទ្ធ ពី​ព្រោះ​នៅ​ថ្ងៃ​នោះ ទ្រង់​បាន​ឈប់​សំរាក​ពី​គ្រប់​ទាំង​ការ​ដែល​ទ្រង់​បាន​បង្កើត​បាន​ធ្វើ។
    ៤ នេះ​ហើយ​ជា​ដើម​កំណើត​នៃ​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ និង​ផែនដី ក្នុង​កាល​ដែល​បាន​កើត​មក។
    មនុស្ស​ដើម​ដំបូង​បង្អស់
    បុរស និង ស្ត្រី នៅ​ក្នុង​សួន​អេដែន
    គឺ​នៅ​វេលា​ដែល​ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​បាន​ធ្វើ​ផែនដី និង​ផ្ទៃ​មេឃ​នោះ​ឯង ៥ រីឯ​នៅ​ផែនដី​នោះ​មិន​ទាន់​មាន​អ្វី​ដុះ​នៅ​ឡើយ​ទេ​ក៏​មិន​ទាន់​មាន​តិណជាតិ​ណា​នៅ​វាល​ដែរ ពី​ព្រោះ​ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មិន​បាន​បង្អុរ​ភ្លៀង​មក​លើ​ផែនដី​សោះ ហើយ​ក៏​គ្មាន​មនុស្ស​ណា​នឹង​ភ្ជួររាស់​ដី​ផង ៦ គ្រាន់​តែ​មាន​ចំហាយ​ឡើង​ពី​ដី​មក​ស្រោចស្រប់​លើ​ផែនដី​ប៉ុណ្ណោះ។ ៧ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​យក​ធូលី​ដីមក​សូន​ធ្វើ​ជា​មនុស្ស ទ្រង់​ផ្លុំ​ខ្យល់​ដង្ហើម​ជីវិត​បញ្ចូល​ទៅ​ក្នុង​រន្ធ​ច្រមុះ នោះ​ក៏​ត្រឡប់​ជា​មាន​ព្រលឹង​រស់​ឡើង។
    ៨ រួច​ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ធ្វើ​សួនច្បារ​១​នៅ​ស្រុក​អេដែន​ទិស​ខាង​កើត ក៏​ដាក់​មនុស្ស​ដែល​ទ្រង់​បាន​សូន​ធ្វើ​ឲ្យ​នៅ​ទី​នោះ ៩ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ក៏​ធ្វើ​ឲ្យ​ដី​ដុះ​គ្រប់​អស់​ទាំង​ដើម​ឈើ​ដែល​គួរ​ពិចពិលរមឹលមើល ហើយ​សំរាប់​ជា​អាហារ​ផង ក៏​ដាំ​ដើម​ជីវិត​នឹង​ដើម​សំរាប់​ដឹង​ខុស​ត្រូវនៅ​កណ្តាល​សួនច្បារ​នោះ​ដែរ ១០ មាន​ទន្លេ​១​ហូរ​ចេញ​ពី​ស្រុក​អេដែន​មក​ស្រោច​សួនច្បារ​នោះ រួច​ហូរ​បែក​ពី​នោះ​ទៅ​ជា​៤​មុខ ១១ ទី​១​ឈ្មោះ​ពិសុន គឺ​ជា​ទន្លេ​ដែល​ហូរ​ព័ទ្ធ​ស្រុក​ហាវីឡា​ដែល​មាន​មាស ១២ មាស​ដែល​មក​ពី​ស្រុក​នោះ​ជា​មាស​យ៉ាង​ល្អ ក៏​មាន​ទាំង​ប្តេល្លាម និង​ត្បូង​អូនីក្ស​ផង ១៣ ទី​២​ឈ្មោះ​គីហុន គឺ​ជា​ទន្លេ​ដែល​ហូរ​ព័ទ្ធ​ស្រុក​គូស ១៤ ទី​៣​ឈ្មោះ​ហ៊ីដេកែល គឺ​ជា​ទន្លេ​ដែល​ហូរ​ចាក់​ទៅ​ខាង​កើត​ស្រុក​អាសស៊ើរ ហើយ​ទន្លេ​ទី៤​ឈ្មោះ​អ៊ើប្រាត ១៥ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​យក​អ័ដាម​ទៅ​ដាក់​នៅ​ក្នុង​សួនច្បារ​អេដែន ឲ្យ​គាត់​ធ្វើ​ការ​ហើយ​ថែ​រក្សា ១៦ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​បង្គាប់​ទៅ​អ័ដាម​ថា ឯង​នឹង​ស៊ី​ផ្លែ​ទាំង​អស់​ក្នុង​សួនច្បារ​នេះ​បាន​តាម​ចិត្ត ១៧ តែ​ឯ​ត្រង់​ដើម​ដឹង​ខុស​ត្រូវ នោះ​មិន​ត្រូវ​ឲ្យ​ឯង​ស៊ី​ផល​ឡើយ ដ្បិត​នៅ​ថ្ងៃ​ណា​ដែល​ឯង​ស៊ី នោះ​នឹង​ត្រូវ​ស្លាប់​ជា​មិន​ខាន។
    ១៨ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​មាន​ព្រះបន្ទូល​ថា ដែល​មនុស្ស​នេះ​នៅ​តែ​ម្នាក់​ឯង នោះ​មិន​ស្រួល​ទេ អញ​នឹង​ធ្វើ​ឲ្យ​មាន​ម្នាក់​ជា​ជំនួយ​សំរាប់​ជួយ​វា ១៩ ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​បាន​យក​ដី​មក​សូន​ធ្វើ​គ្រប់​ទាំង​សត្វ​ជើង​៤ និង​សត្វ​ហើរ​ទាំង​ប៉ុន្មាន រួច​ក៏​នាំ​មក​ឯ​អ័ដាម ដើម្បី​ឲ្យ​ដឹង​ជា​គាត់​នឹង​ហៅ​យ៉ាង​ដូច​ម្តេច ឯ​ឈ្មោះ​ណា​ដែល​អ័ដាម​បាន​ដាក់​ឲ្យ​ដល់​ជីវិត​ផង​ទាំងឡាយ នោះ​បាន​សំរេច​ជា​ឈ្មោះ​របស់​សត្វ​នោះ​ឯង ២០ អ័ដាម​ដាក់​ឈ្មោះ​ឲ្យ​ដល់​គ្រប់​ទាំង​សត្វ​ស្រុក សត្វ​ព្រៃ និង​សត្វ​ហើរ​លើ​អាកាស​ទាំង​ប៉ុន្មាន​ជា​ស្រេច តែ​មិន​ឃើញ​មាន​ជំនួយ​ណា​សំរាប់​ឲ្យ​ជួយ​គាត់​សោះ ២១ នោះ​ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​ទ្រង់​ធ្វើ​ឲ្យ​អ័ដាម​ដេក​លក់​ស៊ប់​ទៅ រួច​ទ្រង់​យក​ឆ្អឹង​ជំនីរ​គាត់​១ ហើយ​ភ្ជិត​សាច់​ទៅ​វិញ ២២ រីឯ​ឆ្អឹង​ដែល​ព្រះយេហូវ៉ា​ដ៏​ជា​ព្រះ​បាន​យក​ពី​អ័ដាម​មក នោះ​ទ្រង់​ជប​ឲ្យ​កើត​ឡើង​ជា​មនុស្ស​ស្រី ក៏​នាំ​ទៅ​អ័ដាម ២៣ អ័ដាម​ក៏​ថា នេះ​ហើយ​ជា​ឆ្អឹង​ពី​ឆ្អឹង​អញ ជា​សាច់​ពី​សាច់​អញ និង​ត្រូវ​ហៅ​ថា «ស្ត្រី» ពី​ព្រោះ​បាន​យក​ចេញ​ពី​បុរស​មក ២៤ ដោយ​ហេតុ​នោះ បាន​ជា​មនុស្ស​ប្រុស​នឹង​លា​ចេញ​ពី​ឪពុក​ម្តាយ​ខ្លួន ទៅ​នៅ​ជាប់​នឹង​ប្រពន្ធ​វិញ ហើយ​អ្នក​ទាំង​២​នោះ​នឹង​ត្រឡប់​ជា​សាច់​តែ​១​សុទ្ធ ២៥ រីឯ​អ័ដាម នឹង​ប្រពន្ធ​គាត់​ក៏​នៅ​ជា​អាក្រាត​ទទេ ឥត​មាន​សេចក្តី​អៀនខ្មាស​ឡើយ។
</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following to get the array of html:

```
String[] arrayHtml= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.GE);
```

Then set the html to your view:

```
details.setText(Html.fromHtml(arrayHtml[0]));
```

UPDATE:
Seems like CData is not supported for a textview. [Here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) is a list of all supported html tags. There might be more though.

Comment: Thank you very much it working well, but we have to add html tag manually in string. any other way if we want to set the super script only on the number in string?

Comment: you can use spannable text in your textview